# Azure AD-B2C and multiple providers

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to associate more than a login to a user in Azure AD B2C? 
e.g. FB **and** Google +?
I am looking for something like Identity in ASP.net where you can have a user associate multiple log in accounts to the same profile.

Cheers

Alberto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option is supported **only by using Custom Policies** (Built-in policies still lack this function so far).

If you are willing to learn how to build custom policies I would suggest you check the official documentation:

[Azure AD-B2C Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/)

And download the community-driven repo of Azure AD-B2C of custom policies:

[Azure AD-B2C Starter-pack from Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack)

Furthermore, the key points you should understand to add this function are:

- User journeys and all of their components
- Definition of technical profiles
- Claims Schema & Claims transformations for Social Accounts

All of the documentation is available on the above-mentioned link, a quick hint for those already familiar with custom policies is to check out directly this link:

[Social accounts claims transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/social-transformations)

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Linking identities from multiple providers to a single user account is **not currently supported in Azure AD B2C**.

You can vote for this ask in the Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum to help the team prioritize it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10686759-limit-conccurent-multiple-logins-in-b2c-ad

Comment: Linked UV post is not related to the question, and the answer itself is also incorrect.